# Webparts alignment wen viewed in 50% in any browser

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, responsive

Environment: Sharepoint 2013

I have OOTB web parts placed on the homepage of the intranet site.
If viewed at 100% zoom level on any browser, the alignment of web parts is proper

**i.e.** web parts are placed to each other with a proper spacing.

However, if viewed at 50% of the zoom level then the web parts won't be placed anymore to each other.

It gets completely dis-aligned.

**Troubleshooting:**

I have tried using fixed width, but no good.

Any recommendations will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: are you mean you need to show it as responsive design ?

Comment: Webparts alignment to be the same on low or high resolution / screen sizes.